# I baked custard at too much heat, is there a name for what I created?

Tags: oven, custard

Recently a friend from the Americas gave me a simple recipe for custard, I never had custard (or at least not knowingly) and thus wanted to try it out. The recipe in it's original form would be:

> 3-4 eggs
>   1/2 cup sugar
>   1/4 teaspoon salt
>   3 cups milk
>   1 teaspoon vanilla
>   some nutmeg
>
> Blend & put into bowls, put bowls into larger dish filled with water.
>   Put into the oven at 176F & cook for around 45min.

Knowing that I am from Switzerland he tried to translate it to metric (this is the recipe that I got from him):

> 3-4 eggs
>   118ml sugar
>   1.2ml salt
>   709ml milk
>   4.8ml vanilla
>   some nutmeg
>
> Blend & put into bowls, put bowls into larger dish filed with water.
>   Put into the oven at 176**C** & cook for around 45min.

As my oven only does 5C increases I put it in at 180C and didn't spend much time thinking about it. The result does not taste bad at all, but the consistency is less that of a cream (looked up custard on Wikipedia in the end) and more that of supermarket flan.

**Q**: Is there a name for the monstrosity I created or is it still custard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you made is a baked custard, and it sounds like it came out rather well.

A runny/pouring custard is made in a pan on the stove top, rather than baked, but has a similar ratio of ingredients, sometimes with added flour or cornflour to thicken it.